# Getting a single array out of another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some code that is generating this array (broke it up for easy reading):

```
Array ( [0] => 78 ) 78 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 ) 75 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 ) 72 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 ) 68 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 ) 65 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 [5] => 62 ) 62 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 [5] => 62 [6] => 59 ) 59 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 [5] => 62 [6] => 59 [7] => 56 ) 56 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 [5] => 62 [6] => 59 [7] => 56 [8] => 37 ) 37 
Array ( [0] => 78 [1] => 75 [2] => 72 [3] => 68 [4] => 65 [5] => 62 [6] => 59 [7] => 56 [8] => 37 [9] => 36 ) 36
```

What I need is the last array. The one that has all the numbers individually stored. How can  I do this? In php btw.

Comment: those are individual arrays as is. is there some other array that contains these that you're not showing?

Comment: Tell us how you are getting this list of arrays first

Comment: If you use count($your_array) it counts the rows well or not??...if count is good then you can retrieve the last row something like $row =  $your_array[count($your_array)-1];

Answer (score 2):

Try `array_pop($array)`. It will pop the last element from array and return it.

update:

```
$buffer = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $buffer = array_pop($array);
}
```

I think this is what you mean.

Comment: If you need to keep arrays intact, use `end($array); echo current($array);`

Answer (score 0):

let name your array as $long_arr

```
$target_array = array_values($long_arr); 
var_dump($target_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This comment did it for me:

If you use count($your_array) it counts the rows well or not??...if count is good then you can retrieve the last row something like $row = $your_array[count($your_array)-1]; – Robert Rozas 18 hours ago